# Python Dropdown Menu to Choose Model to Show Accuracy and Confusion Matrix

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I'm using ipywidgets to create a dropdown menu to choose from different models, and then have a confusion matrix visualization and accuracy score output. I have the dropdown menu created, but I do not know how to link this to different code to run the models and have this output shown.

Additionally, if you know how to create a button to save export the accuracies generated, that would be very appreciated.

```
# Dropdown menu
menu = widgets.Dropdown(
    options= ['Decision Tree', 'Random Forest'],
    value= 'Decision Tree',
    description='Selection:',
    disabled=False,
)
display(menu)

# First Model
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
dt = dt.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_dt = dt.predict(x_test)

matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_dt)
sns.heatmap(matrix, annot=True)
plt.show()
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_dt))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a single function that

1 - takes input from a widget

2 - decides based on the input which model to run.

3 - runs the model and displays the output.

Without a minimal example it's hard to figure out exactly how to use your code, but could try something like the below.

```
output = ipywidgets.Output()

def run_from_widget(w):
    if w.value == 'Decision Tree':
        dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42
        dt = dt.fit(x_train, y_train)
        y_dt = dt.predict(x_test)

        matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_dt)
        sns.heatmap(matrix, annot=True)
        with output:
            plt.show()
            print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_dt))

menu = widgets.Dropdown(
    options= ['Decision Tree', 'Random Forest'],
    value= 'Decision Tree',
    description='Selection:',
    disabled=False,
)

menu.observe(run_from_widget)
display(menu)
display(output)
```